# Evaluate the limit of function presented as a series

Tags: limits, fourier-analysis

This is an additional exercise given in my Fourier analysis course.

> Define $F(t)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty (-1)^n e^{-2n^2t^2}, \,t>0$, Prove that
>
> 1. $\lim_{t\to \infty}F(t)=1$.
> 2. $\lim_{t\to 0}\bigg(F(t)-\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{t}e^{-\frac{\pi^2}{8t^2}}\bigg)=0$.

---

**My Try**

For Question 1, for $t>1$ the series is uniformly convergent, hence $\exists N, |\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty (-1)^n e^{-2n^2t^2}-\sum_{n=-N}^N (-1)^n e^{-2n^2t^2}|<\epsilon, \forall t>1$.

Since $\sum_{n=-N}^N (-1)^n e^{-2n^2t^2}\to 1$ as $t\to \infty$, $\exists M, \forall t>M,|\sum_{n=-N}^N (-1)^n e^{-2n^2t^2}-1|<\epsilon$, hence $\forall t>M,|\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty (-1)^n e^{-2n^2t^2}-1|<2\epsilon$.

But I am not sure how to solve Q2. Any suggestion is appreciated.